# Closing a client socket from server print out multiple string that I already printed

Tags: c, network-programming

I create a server that receive http request and print that request. I can successfully print out http request that I receive without closing that client socket but when I close the client socket, the server print out multiple http request that I already printed out before.
This is my code:

```
int handleConnection(int sockfd)
{
    // sockfd is new_sockfd

    char fullReq[MAX_HEADER_SIZE];

    receiveReq(sockfd, fullReq);

    printf("fullReq in handleConnection\n%s", fullReq);
    close(sockfd); // bug occur when I close it
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code of recvReq function:

```
int receiveReq(int sockfd, char *fullReq)
{

    char buffer[1];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    char *bufferPtr = buffer;

    char terminators[] = {'\r', '\n'};

    int number_of_requests = 0;
    int matchedTerminators = 0;
    
    while(number_of_requests <= MAX_HEADER_SIZE)
    {
        if(matchedTerminators >= 4)
            break;

        recv(sockfd, bufferPtr, 1, 0);
        strncat(fullReq, bufferPtr, 1);
        number_of_requests++;

        if(buffer[0] == terminators[0] || buffer[0] == terminators[1])
            matchedTerminators++;
        else
            matchedTerminators = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output if I didn't close the socket:

```
fullReq in handleConnection
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Output if I close the socket:

```
fullReq in handleConnection
GET / HTTP/1.1

fullReq in handleConnection
GET / HTTP/1.1

fullReq in handleConnection
GET / HTTP/1.1

more...
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I already added the code of receiveReq function.

Comment: For starters, if you use `strncat` you should make sure it actually starts at the begin. That is, before the first call you should set `fullReq[0]` to `'\0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for the return code of `recv`. When the client socket closes, `recv` is likely to fail (depends on how you open your server's socket), and `bufferPtr` will remain with the same contents, the last request. You can detect if `recv` failed, for example because the client socket has closed, by checking if it has returned -1. You can check the man pages for recv on various reasons `recv` might have failed.

Comment: Note thar recv() returns 0 if the peer closes the link.

Comment: Thanks, instead of adding buffer directly to fullReq in while loop, I create a variable call temp_fullReq and I add buffer to it. If server successfully receive the request I copy temp_fullReq to fullReq.

Comment: I still don't understand why my program print out multiple string just before recv if fail?